# findViewById returns null on a Fragment with setRetainInstance(true)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a more responsive layout, so I opted to use the setRetainInstance on my fragment to prevent re-requesting my webservice on device rotation. The problem is that when I try to get the reference to a TextView in my Fragment Activity from within the fragment, the findViewById always returns null.

```
this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_currentAddress)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: in fragment use getView().findViewById(R.id.textView_currentAddress)

Comment: Can you post some more code ?